# How do you replace part of a string with a variable when the string uses quotation marks?

Tags: string, variables, arduino

I have an arduino HTTP.POST that I'm trying to make with a string:

```
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"title\": \"distance\", \"content\": \"miles\"}");
```

This properly posts this:

"{"title": "distance", "content": "miles"}"

I want to replace the word *miles* with a variable (an integer).

I tried this:

```
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"title\": \"distance\", \"content\": '\"' + miles + '\"'}");
```

But I get an HTTP 400 (bad request) response when using this.  What is the proper way to replace text in a string with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for a while, here is an answer that works:

```
String string_one = "{\"title\": \"distance\", \"content\": \"";
String string_two = "\"}";
String final_string = string_one + miles + string_two;
int httpResponseCode = http.POST(final_string);
```

You just combine them as strings.